# How to solve the Issue of Reactstrap Navbar code

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

Reactstrap navbar is not working inside the menu component but when I import the button and use it inside the menu component it is working then. What's the issue I am not getting although I am using the scss and have imported the bootstrap.css file in the styles.scss file and using the styles.scss file in the root app.js file.

Here is my menu.js file

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';



const Menu = (props) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar color="light">
        <NavbarBrand href="/">reactstrap</NavbarBrand>
        <NavbarToggler onClick={toggle} />
        <Collapse isOpen={isOpen} navbar>
          <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="/components/">Components</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem>
              <NavLink href="https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap">GitHub</NavLink>
            </NavItem>
            <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
              <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                Options
              </DropdownToggle>
              <DropdownMenu right>
                <DropdownItem>
                  Option 1
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem>
                  Option 2
                </DropdownItem>
                <DropdownItem divider />
                <DropdownItem>
                  Reset
                </DropdownItem>
              </DropdownMenu>
            </UncontrolledDropdown>
          </Nav>
        </Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call a function for that dropdown like that

```
  const toggle = () => setDropdownOpen(prevState => !prevState);

    return (
        <Dropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle}>
        <DropdownToggle caret>
            Dropdown
            </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
            <DropdownItem header>Header</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem>Some Action</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem disabled>Action (disabled)</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem divider />
            <DropdownItem>Foo Action</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem>Bar Action</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem>Quo Action</DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
    );
    }
```